# UnicodeDecodeError from sound file

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, utf-8, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make a speech recogniser in Python using Google speech API. I've been using and adapting the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19828908/4961615) (converted to Python3). I'm using an audio file on my computer that's been converted from mp3 to flac 16000 Hz (as specified in the original code) using an online converter. When running the code I get this error:

```
$ python3 speech_api.py 02-29-2016_00-12_msg1.flac 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speech_api.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 9: invalid start byte
```

This is my code. (I'm sure there are also still things that don't work in Python3, as I've been trying to adapt it and am new to `urllib`...)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
try:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print('Usage: transcribe.py <file>')
    sys.exit(1)

with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()

req = urllib.request('https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html', data=data, headers={'Content-type': 'audio/x-flac; rate=16000'})

try:
    ret = urllib.urlopen(req)
except urllib.URLError:
    print("Error Transcribing Voicemail")
    sys.exit(1)

resp = ret.read()
text = json.loads(resp)['hypotheses'][0]['utterance']
print(text)
```

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: Please share the code. How are you opening the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the file in *binary mode*:

```
open(filename, 'wb')
```

Note the `'b'`, or the file will be treated as text and decoded to Unicode.

Comment: Thanks! I think this might have solved that part of my problem. It's not quite working at the moment though because it can't read the audio file with `read`. But I guess that's a different question.

Comment: I finally ended up using `rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)` to read audio file, after downloading Anaconda to get the relevant packages. The above wouldn't work to read audio files in Python3, but it solved the UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: @Ingrid: it'll work to read any binary file. It may not make your use-case easier, but audio files are *just binary content* to Python.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, you're absolutely right! Worked as well with `with open(filename, 'rb') as f: data = f.read()`. Must have been some other error I didn't understand earlier.