# In Django, trying to encode .wav file using base64 encoding , but getting this error

Tags: django, api, encoding, base64, wav

```
audio_content = open("okay.wav").read()
AUDIO_FILE = base64.b64encode(audio_content)
```

[image: screen shot of the error I am getting]

I am trying to encode .wav file using base64 encoding but getting this error

any suggestion ??

Comment: I think this is a duplicate to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724820/unicodedecodeerror-from-sound-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError from sound file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724820/unicodedecodeerror-from-sound-file)